# How to update Firebase SDK in Xcode

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods

Could anyone explain how to update the firebase SDK? I found many tutorials on how to install a firebase SDK, but I am totally confused on how to update it. I've also checked this [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup) out, but I still don't see how to update it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/pod-install-vs-update.html

> Use `pod update [PODNAME]` only when you want to update pods to a newer version.

Comment: ok, so I just simply open the old pod and update it in terminal, correct? do I need to do anything with the GoogleService-Info.plist ?

Comment: Just run the command in the same way you ran `pod install`.  Nothing else needs to change.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the version in the Podfile or run `pod update`

Comment: how can I define the version of the podfile?

Comment: `pod {framework name}, '~> {version}' ` [Podfile guides](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html)